# Meaning of the Oscar Wilde quote about “never have an emotion that is unbecoming”

Tags: quotes

Came across this quote in an "Inspirations" booklet attributed to Oscar Wilde:

> The secret of life is never have an emotion that is unbecoming.

Found the related quote by Henry Wotton:

> The secret of remaining young is to never have an emotion that is unbecoming.

This is a double rainbow for me. What's inspiring about this quote? Seems a bit tragic, or contradictory, if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Unbecoming' means 'unattractive' or ugly - so having an emotion such as anger, perhaps, greed, or sadness, frustration etc, might contort your face and make you appear ugly or be 'unbecoming' to you.

Wilde is suggesting you avoid such emotions as they do not become you - this 'become you' by the way, is an expression, a bit archaic - it means 'suit you' or 'go well with your style' or 'make you look good'.

Don't confuse this expression with the normal meaning of 'becoming' - eg 'transforming, changing' - because it's nothing to do with that at all! It is not about 'becoming something' developing advancing etc. No! It's a totally different expression.

So what he's saying, is the secret of life is to remain attractive, pretty, handsome, composed - by never having a negative emotion.

A bit like an earlier version of 'don't worry - be happy!' so that's why it's in your inspirational quotes book.

There is humour in it, too - what is the likelihood of never feeling a negative emotion, and feeling happy all the time? Not much! So Wilde is also commenting on 'why we get old' - which is really quite funny.

It's like he is looking at society getting old, at all our anger, pain, grief etc, and saying 'ah! - if only....'

PS I love your expression of 'a double rainbow!' Cute!☃️